# Thread queue with timeout in VB . NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, timeout

I have a function which does some tasks in database trough a function contained in a dll. That function need to be executed many times with different parameters, but sometimes it takes too much time and need to kill the process and continue with the queue. The function in de dll doesn't have any timeout option, so I tried to control this creating a thread. I'm not used to work with threads, but after some research I made something like this code:

```
 Dim Thread As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf Function)
    Thread.Start()
    Thread.Join(maxTime)

    If(Thread.IsAlive) Then

        WriteLogFile("Error [....]")
        Thread.Abort()
    End If
```

Probabily it isn't the smartier or most elegant way to do it, but it seemed to work when I tested it, but now I see that the "timeout" doesn't work. Well, it seems to work well if I set the timeout with a few seconds. But if I set it to 10 minutes, which is what I need, takes much more time than 10 minutes. I can expect that maybe Thread.join() is not totally accurate, but the difference is not jsut few seconds.

I tried many similar ways, so i don't know if i have the right focus of the problem. Maybe the malfunction of the code comes from the way of work of the .dll function, but first I need to discard the posibility of a mistake from myself (which i think is more probabily).

¿Can anyone tell me where is the mistake, or another way of doing this safer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thread.Join() is accurate to 16 msec.  What happens next is not, the odds that you can *actually* abort a thread are never that good.  A thread must be in the right state to allow an abort, that almost always requires it to be executing managed code.  Always high odds that it is off in the woods executing native code.  The only way to do this reliably, quickly and safely is to run that code in a separate process.  One you can always Kill().

Comment: Had some troubles to implement the separated process due the nature of the unmanaged code, but I think I achieved to do the work.

In addition, this was very instructive because I never worked with this stuff, and helped me to understand remains of detached, commented code from older versions.

Thanks a lot, Hans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered from comment of Hans. In order to control the execution of unmanaged code, threads can't provide a proper handling to finalize the function, so to implement a true timeout limiter, is needed to launch that function inside other project called as a process, to be able to call Kill() function, which really stops the process.